# Can I force the system mouse cursor image for a selected application?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, cursor

**Short Question**
Is it possible to force the system mouse cursor image to a fixed image (Arrow) on an application by application basis?

**Background**
I have been trying to hide an annoying hourglass flicker that I see when using Visio 2010 see [my post](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=3634.0) on Visio Guy's website for more details.  As of right now, I am unable to achieve this with Visio so I am looking at an OS solution.

The ideal solution would set the mouse cursor to an arrow, or some other system pointer, and not allow it to change **only** while the Visio application is in focus.

**System Information**
*OS:* Windows 7 (64 and 32 bit)